# how to get number of pcf instances running in java code?

Tags: paas, spring-restcontroller, cloud-foundry

I have an app that uses spring rest and deployed on PCF. Now inside the code I have to get the number of PCF instances running currently. Can anyone help?

Comment: By "PCF Instances" do you mean the number of instances of your app running in an org and a space, the number of instances of your app running across one whole PCF, or the number PCFs installed across a business?

Comment: I mean the number of instances of my app running in an org and a space

Answer (score 3):

Before I answer this - why do you want to know? It's an anti-pattern for cloud native apps to know about their peers; they should each be working in total isolation.

You can discover this by looking up application details by GUID in the CloudController. You can get your current app's GUID in the `VCAP_APPLICATION` environment variable.

https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/245/apps/get_app_summary.html

In order to hit the CloudController your app will need to know the system domain of your Cloud Foundry (eg `api.mycf.com`) and credentials that allow it to make that request.